# get the latest version from an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

I have an array of version numbers called **unique_versions** that keeps on increasing :

```
1.7.16
1.7.14
1.7.13
1.7.12
1.7.9
1.7.7
1.7.5
1.7.4
1.7.2
1.6.2
1.2.1
1.2.0
1.1.0
0.0.1
```

and I need to get the latest(1.7.16) from the array. What the most elegant ruby way of doing it ? I get this array by the following code :

```
require "json"
require "open-uri"
require 'openssl'

string_object = open("https://xxx", :http_basic_authentication=>["xxx"], :ssl_verify_mode=>OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
json_file = JSON.parse(string_object.read)
version_array = Array.new
json_file["results"].each do |version|
    version_array.push(version["version"].sub /-.*$/, '')
end
unique_versions=(version_array.uniq)
```

Comment: @Stefan note that he _strips_ the `-beta.2` parts in a preprocessing step

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version handling is already implemented in `Gem::Version` (and maybe others), no need to reinvent the wheel.

```
string_versions.max_by{ |s| Gem::Version.new(s) } # => "1.7.16"
```

Comment: great, just what I needed.

Comment: I suggest using [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) instead of `sort_by`, since it's O(*n*) rather than O(*n²*):  `string_versions.max_by {|s| Gem::Version.new(s) }`

Comment: @Jordan: of course, thanks. But `sort_by` isn't O(N^2).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ruby uses Quicksort. [Quicksort is O(n²) in the worst case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis). Perhaps you're thinking of the average case, for which it's O(n log n). My bad for not being more specific. Of course, it depends on how Ruby chooses its pivots, which I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work

```
unique_versions.sort_by { |version| version.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
 => ["0.0.1", "1.1.0", "1.2.0", "1.2.1", "1.6.2", "1.7.2", "1.7.4", "1.7.5", "1.7.7", "1.7.9", "1.7.12", "1.7.13", "1.7.14", "1.7.16"]
```

so

```
unique_versions.max_by { |version| version.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
 => "1.7.16"
```

Note that you can rewrite this part

```
version_array = Array.new
json_file["results"].each do |version|
    version_array.push(version["version"].sub /-.*$/, '')
end
unique_versions=(version_array.uniq)
```

in something like

```
 unique_versions = json_file["results"].map { |version| version["version"].sub /-.*$/, '' }.uniq
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great but I had to accept the other one because of its elegance :)

Comment: Do not worry :)